# Writing tests for user authentication with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am currently trying to write unit tests for user authentication in rails and I keep running into a problem.

I am trying to test the following method:

```
def reset_session_token!
  self.session_token = User.generate_session_token
  self.save!
  self.session_token
end
```

with the following unit test:

```
let(:valid_user) { User.new(user_name: 'Name', password: 'abcdefghijkl')}

it "should set the session_token" do     
  valid_user.reset_session_token!

  expect(valid_user.session_token).not_to be_nil
end
```

but the test fails with the error `Validation failed: User name has already been taken`. I suspect that it is because `reset_session_token!` calls save on the user instance but this is necessary for the method to work properly. How can I get around this?

Comment: you can `stub` method `save!`

Comment: Cool that works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Oleg Sobchuk's comment I was able to figure out how to deal with the `save!` method.

Since `stub` has been deprecated I used `allow_any_instance_of` with `receive` instead. Here is what I did:

```
it "should set the session_token" do
  allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:save!).and_return(nil)
  valid_user.reset_session_token!

  expect(valid_user.session_token).not_to be_nil
end
```